# Show data from related tables (Django)

Tags: python, django

I have an ApiRest with 2 related tables and i want to show the data in Json like the documentation i post in the serializers Image.

**Here is my Project:**

this is my [Model.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ubitl.png) i related Movimientos with Productos table

```
class Movimientos(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Total = models.IntegerField()
    Modo_Stock = models.IntegerField()
    Modo_Ventas = models.IntegerField()
    Fecha = models.DateField()
    Hora = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    Cantidad = models.IntegerField()
    Importe = models.IntegerField()
    Descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Prod = models.ManyToManyField(Productos)
    # Caja = models.ForeignKey(Cajas, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('Fecha',)
```

this is my [Serializers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbgrC.png), like documentation i create the .create() method but it doesnt work

```
class ProductosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Productos
        fields = '__all__'

class MovimientosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    Prod = ProductosSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Movimientos
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        Prod_data = validated_data.pop('Prod')
        mov = Movimientos.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for pro_data in Prod_data:
            Productos.objects.create(mov=mov, **pro_data)
        return mov
```

my [Views and Urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mChW.png)

```
class MovimientosList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Movimientos.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovimientosSerializer

class MovimientosDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Movimientos.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovimientosSerializer

class MovimientosListSearch(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    search_fields = ['Descripcion']
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    queryset = Movimientos.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovimientosSerializer

def consulta(request, desde, hasta):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        resultados = serializers.serialize('json', Movimientos.objects.filter(Fecha__range=[desde, hasta]))
        return HttpResponse(resultados)
```

The Urls.py

```
path('movimientos/', mov_views.MovimientosList.as_view(), name='movimientos'),
path('movimientos/<int:pk>/', mov_views.MovimientosDetail.as_view()),
path('movimientos/search/', mov_views.MovimientosListSearch.as_view()),
path('movimientos/entrefechas/<str:desde>/<str:hasta>/', mov_views.consulta),
```

**And the POST Error**
[POST - Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GRPW.png)

JSON:

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Total": 233,
    "Modo_Stock": 2,
    "Modo_Ventas": 2,
    "Fecha": "2019-11-01",
    "Hora": "15:23:00",
    "Cantidad": 34,
    "Importe": 233,
    "Descripcion": "Venta",
    "Prod": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Codigo_Barra": "12342352",
            "Codigo_Producto": "324234",
            "Descripcion": "Cervezas",
            "Precio_Compra": 80,
            "Precio_Venta": 130,
            "Stock_Actual": 58
        }
    ]
}


    raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: Productos() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mov'
[09/Nov/2019 09:57:31] "POST /movimientos/ HTTP/1.1" 500 17510
```

I want to show the json like the documentation, but i can´t do the POST.

I think is the .create() function what is causing problems.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode I did not downvote, but please share *code* itself. *Not* **images** of code. Images are large, inconvenient, one can not easily copy/edit it locally, people who have trouble with sight can not use tools to help them read the code, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pass a parameter `mov` to `Productos.objects.create(mov=mov, ...)`, since this is a many-to-many relation, you should alter the relation after the creation of the two objects, like:

```
class MovimientosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Prod = ProductosSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Movimientos
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        Prod_data = validated_data.pop('Prod')
        mov = Movimientos.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for pro_data in Prod_data:
            product = Productos.objects.create(**pro_data)
            mov.Prod.add(product)
        return mov
```

> **Note**: normally class names are written in `PerlCase` (like you did correctly), but attributes are written [`snake_case` [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case), so `prod` instead of <s>`Prod`</s>, `modo_ventas` instead of <s>`Modo_Ventas`</s>, etc.